# How to store objects created in a loop inside array defined outside of loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, global-variables

I have the following for loop in which `this_block` gets created and then filled in:

```
for (i = learning_trial_idx.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  target = Math.floor(Math.random())

  these_trials = learning_trial_idx.filter(x => x.from != target)

  this_block = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < these_trials.length; i++) {
      this_block.push(these_trials[i])
  }

  this_block = this_block.filter(function (a) {
    var key = a.to + '|' + a.from;
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = true;
        return true;
      }
    }, Object.create(null));
}
```

How can I go about storing `this_block` each time into something like `const all_blocks = {}`, which is defined outside of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by declaring first `const allBlocks = { thisBlock: [] }` and `push`-ing inside `thisBlock` inside the `for` loop: `allBlocks.thisBlock.push(theseTrials[i])`